# What is sub-pixel convolution?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am working on a super-resolution project. And for now, I am using Transposed Convolution for upsampling the image. But I have heard a lot that sub-pixel convolutions do it better. So what is subpixel convolution and the math behind it? And Why it is better than transposed convolution? (some example would be great)

Answer (score 2):

Image convolution centers on interpolation.

Sub-pixel rendering is based on the fact that a pixel is composed of three color components, say R G B horizontally. A white pixel of width 2/3 on the border of a white area can be rendered in false color as R G. Especially font rendering is improved by sub-pixel rendering.

The geometry of the color components may vary, like B G R. A wrong geometry will destroy the intended extra sharpness. Also note that the positive effect is on the x axis.

Consider a Pixel #cccccc two third width: for instance #ffff00. And a half pixel #ff8800. More or less. Should weight the green component higher probably.

Sub-pixel convolution just operates with these sub-pixels, instead just till pixel level. Your data model has for the x coordinate a 3 times higher resolution, and combines triples in a special way.

Gray scale images may exploit sub pixel rendering best.

*I should tell, I did little with sub-pixel rendering and at the time it was relatively new.*

Answer (score 2):

Seems in context of super resolution it's called pixel shuffle layer (but maybe it's just a special case of sub-pixel convolution).

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PixelShuffle.html

Paper: [Real-Time Single Image and Video Super-Resolution Using an Efficient Sub-Pixel Convolutional Neural Network by Shi et. al (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05158.pdf)